# run spring boot mongodb api application in docker. Exception opening socket error

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, javabeans

I was trying to run a spring boot mongodb api application in docker but encounter the Exception opening socket error.

```
Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017  
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
```

After some research I added @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class}) in my main class

```
package com.example.demo;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;



@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})

public class Main {




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

But I got this error while trying to run the application

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field studentRepository in com.example.demo.controllers.StudentController required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'mongoTemplate' in your configuration.
```

The application could run very well on localhost before this. Any idea what should I do?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MongoProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MongoProject</name>
    <description>mongodb with Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>

                    <mainClass>com.example.demo.Main</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>

                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.example.demo.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=testing
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

Comment: Is MongoDB running inside the same docker container?

Comment: `localhost` in a docker container (your `spring.data.mongodb.host`) will not be resolved to your docker host, but it will be your docker container itself.

Comment: how can I tell if MongoDB is running inside the same docker container?@EdgarDomingues

Comment: can u explain more? :D I am kinda new to all this, what should I do to fix it. @wjans

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) question.

Comment: @tyler How did you started the MongoDB server?

Comment: spring.data.mongodb.host = host.docker.internal in application properties works!